# How to create a pojo file for json response in java with jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, pojo

Here is my json response from an API.

```
{
  "job_1": {
  "metaData": {},
  "extractedData": {
      "score_a": [1,2,3,4],
      "score_b": [40,40,72,136],
      "score_c": [3,3.5,3,2,3,9],
      "score_d": [1659752409254420,1659752416354536,1659752424695028,1659752431823242 ]
  }
  }
}
```

In response job_1 can be vary. maybe its job_3 or job_4.

How to create a pojo file for this response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this dynamic `job_*` naming is not a good practice, you should use lists and maybe an id field for that

Comment: same holds for `score_*`, you could do something like `{"score_type": "A", "value": [1,2,3]}`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the request so that each job is unlabeled in request body to be considered as an object in the list

The request is like this :

```
{
"jobs":[
 {
    "metaData": {},
    "extractedData": {
        "score_a": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "score_b": [
            40,
            40,
            72,
            136
        ],
        "score_c": [
            3,
            3.5,
            3,
            2,
            3,
            9
        ],
        "score_d": [
            1659752409254420,
            1659752416354536,
            1659752424695028,
            1659752431823242
        ]
    }
},
     {
    "metaData": {},
    "extractedData": {
        "score_a": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "score_b": [
            40,
            40,
            72,
            136
        ],
        "score_c": [
            3,
            3.5,
            3,
            2,
            3,
            9
        ],
        "score_d": [
            1659752409254420,
            1659752416354536,
            1659752424695028,
            1659752431823242
        ]
    }
}
]
}
```

With the addition annotation **@JsonSerialize** to metadata to allow display of an object that does not contain elements

```
public class response {
  List<job> jobs;

  public static class job {

    MetaData metaData;
    ExtractedData extractedData;

  @JsonSerialize
  public static class MetaData {

    //insert code

  }

  public static class ExtractedData {

     List<Integer> score_a;
     List<Integer> score_b;
     List<Integer> score_c;
     List<Long> score_d;

  }
 }
}
```

I tried it like this

```
@Controller
public class test {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<response> testPost(@RequestBody response res) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(res);

  }

}
```

Comment: Is it solve the dynamic key names such as job_1, job_2 ...?

Comment: yes , job_1 ,job_2 The names of the objects that will be stored in the list<job>

Comment: no it won't, it is an object in a question and you parse it as a list

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. I'm new to this.

Comment: @vladtkachuk Because may contain a number of objects

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav I could not implement the previous code, so I modified it, I hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap to handle dynamic keys job_1 can vary. maybe it's job_3 or job_4.

```
public class response {
  HashMap<String, job> jobs;

  public static class job {

    MetaData metaData;
    ExtractedData extractedData;

  @JsonSerialize
  public static class MetaData {

    //insert code

  }

  public static class ExtractedData {

     List<Integer> score_a;
     List<Integer> score_b;
     List<Integer> score_c;
     List<Long> score_d;

  }
 }
}
```